# How to right insert or update on same Doctrine2 object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.6

I have this piece of code:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->find($soqlObj1['records'][0]['Id']);

if ($entity === null) {
    $entity = new Representative();
    $em->persist($entity);
}

// we set the values from veeva
$entity->setVeevaRepId($soqlObj1['records'][0]['Id']);
$entity->setEmail($soqlObj1['records'][0]['Email']);
...

$em->flush();
```

And this is part of the entity `Representative`:

```
class Representative
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=false, unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $veeva_rep_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $display_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $avatar_url = 'https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/default_avatar.png';

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $rep_type = "VEEVA";

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $first;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $last;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $bio;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $inactive = false;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $lastLoginAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $lastSyncAt;

    /**
     * @var Territory
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Territory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="territories_id", referencedColumnName="veeva_territory_id")
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $territory;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true, length=150)
     */
    protected $repTokenId;

    ...
}
```

There are a few others columns that are required at DB level (nullable = false at entity level), my question: if the object doesn't exists at DB it will be created or update based on the code I wrote or I need to move each required field into conditional? Which is the right way to achieve this? I am trying to do a `INSERT|UPDATE` based on just one query result

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question: isn't a column constraint valid in both situation?

Comment: @DonCallisto what you mean? I am not following you, can yo be more clear?

Comment: No, can you be more clear? :P I mean, what's the problem. Why do you specify that are "few others columns that are required ad DB LEVEL" ? What does it means "Move each required field into conditional?"

Comment: @DonCallisto I've updated the OP by adding all the fields on `Representative` now, as you can see, there are a few ones that can be nullable while others doesn't that is my doubt, how handle this using just one query, in a few words: if record exists update it, if not create, that is what I am trying to do, did you get now?

Comment: No, sorry, I can't understand what you're trying to do here. Let me please explain: doctrine2 take care itself of "insert or update" situation. What I've asked you is, if there's a mandatory field, is important to know if you are in one on other situation? I mean, if is mandatory, it should have always store a value. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @DonCallisto yes, you're right if it's mandatory it should have always a value and I think yes there will be important to know when I need to create a new record (when not exists on DB already) or update existing one(already exists). Now I'm not following you on this: *"doctrine2 take care itself of "insert or update" situation"* sorry I am just learning

Comment: When you retrieve an entity from db (entity manager), doctrine will know, onto subsequential flush, if the object has to be inserted (so, brand new one) or updated (fetched before). So, because of that, I can't understand your question IF this question is related to constraints of your fields. If it is not, take my comment as a valid answer :)

Comment: @DonCallisto ok, lets change a bit my answer, you have `Representative` entity, right? You want to find a rep by its PK which is `veeva_rep_id` column, right? You want to update record values if it was found otherwise you will create the new record, how will you handle that situation? That's all I am asking here

Comment: I give you my answer below but I still really don't know if I understood correctly :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you retrieved object from db, doctrine itself knows if the next operation will be an update or an insert: you don't have to worry about anything

Your answer is a valid one but I would modify it as follows

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Representative')->find($soqlObj1['records'][0]['Id']);

if ($entity === null) {
    $entity = new Representative();
}

// we set the values from veeva
$entity->setVeevaRepId($soqlObj1['records'][0]['Id']);
$entity->setEmail($soqlObj1['records'][0]['Email']);

$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

As I told you, you don't have to worry about insertion or update, doctrine will do it for you. However, if you need to set certain values only if the object is a new one or if it was fetched from db, just add proper code under `$entity === null` control

Comment: Ok, thx, having this I will ask you: `setEmail()` is required on both: INSERT or UPDATE, in this case you will write the same line twice? One inside the `$entity === null` control (for INSERT) and second outside (for the UPDATE)?

Comment: @ReynierPM: if you have to set a new value in both cases, I will put definitely one time, right before object persist operation. In other case, of course, I would write only were it has sense :P